# get value from one column as variable for subtraction

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data frame with XY's and distances.  what i am trying to do is store the distance as a variable and subtract it from the next distance if X or Y has a value greater than 0

here is a sample df

```
dist     x      y
  0    12.93   99.23
200     0        0
400     0        0
600     0        0
800     0        0
1000    12.46   99.14
1200     0        0
1400     0        0
1600     0        0
1800     0        0
2000    12.01   99.07
```

and this is new df

```
dist     x      y
  0    12.93   99.23
200     0        0
400     0        0
600     0        0
800     0        0
  0    12.46   99.14
 200     0        0
 400     0        0
 600     0        0
 800     0        0
2000    12.01   99.07
```

the last value doesn't matter, but technically, it would be 0.

the idea is that at every know XY, assign the distance as 0 and subtract that distance until the next known XY
in the above example, the distances are rounded numbers, but in reality, they could be like

```
132.05
19.999
1539.65
```

and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with `transform`

```
df.dist-=df.groupby(df.x.ne(0).cumsum())['dist'].transform('first')
df
Out[769]: 
    dist      x      y
0      0  12.93  99.23
1    200   0.00   0.00
2    400   0.00   0.00
3    600   0.00   0.00
4    800   0.00   0.00
5      0  12.46  99.14
6    200   0.00   0.00
7    400   0.00   0.00
8    600   0.00   0.00
9    800   0.00   0.00
10     0  12.01  99.07
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupby` and `apply`, using a custom grouper calculated as follows:

```
grouper = (df['x'].ne(0) | df['y'].ne(0)).cumsum()
df['dist'].groupby(grouper).apply(lambda x: x - x.values[0])

0       0
1     200
2     400
3     600
4     800
5       0
6     200
7     400
8     600
9     800
10      0
Name: dist, dtype: int64
```

Where,

```
grouper

0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    3
dtype: int64
```

The idea is to mark all rows that must be subtracted from the first non-zero value of that corresponding group.

Answer (score 3):

With `where` + `ffill`

```
df['dist'] = df.dist - df.where(df.x.gt(0) | df.y.gt(0)).dist.ffill()

     dist      x      y
0     0.0  12.93  99.23
1   200.0   0.00   0.00
2   400.0   0.00   0.00
3   600.0   0.00   0.00
4   800.0   0.00   0.00
5     0.0  12.46  99.14
6   200.0   0.00   0.00
7   400.0   0.00   0.00
8   600.0   0.00   0.00
9   800.0   0.00   0.00
10    0.0  12.01  99.07
```